# How to transfer paramenters to Partial View in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameters, partial-views

On the Details view I want to display a grid from other table. How to implement it better? I'm trying to do it in a such a way (error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'):

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Appartament/Index.ascx", new { id  = Model.blockhouse_id })%>
```

Here is the code from details view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<testMVC.Models.Blockhouse>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Details</h2>

        <p>
            blockhouse_id:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.blockhouse_id) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            name:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.name) %>
        </p>    

         <p>
            Appartaments:
            <%= Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Appartament/Index.ascx", new { id  = Model.blockhouse_id })%>
        </p>       

</asp:Content>
```

And the code of the Index.ascx controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int blockhouse_id)
        {
            var _appartament = apt.GetBlockAppartaments(blockhouse_id).ToList();
            return View("Index", _appartament);
        }
```

Comment: there is definitly something wrong with your code, and i think you are mistaking views and controllers. Your task sounds trivial, but I think you are doing it wrong. Check out Movies tutorial from http://asp.net/mvc/

Answer (score 10):

`RenderPartial` doesn't have a return value.

Instead of

```
<%= %>
```

Use

```
<% %>
```

- [ASP.NET MVC RenderPartial Compiler Error](http://idevelopdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/aspnet-mvc-renderpartial/)

As for Razor, instead of

```
@
```

Use

```
@{ }
```

Comment: and don't forget the semi-colon in Razor, like I did, which wasn't picked up by the IDE!